# Cannot reach my OpenVPN server from outside anymore

Tags: networking, openvpn, ping, traceroute

I've been using my Raspberry Pi as an OpenVPN server for a long time but I noticed that, after my father called the Telecom's customer support (Telecom is an Italian ISP) because of a problem with landline (I have ADSL), I couldn't connect to my server anymore.
Note: Router's settings didn't change and the port is forwarded.

If I try to traceroute the server from outside, the first 12 or 13 results are ok but then it starts failing (except for the 16th, I don't know why). If I try to ping it, it ends up to be offline (some days ago it was successful).
If I try to do both things from inside the local network (still using the external ip) the traceroute completely fails while the ping is successful.

Any idea? I'd rather talk about it here than with a call center.

Update: if I try to traceroute from inside with `-I` option, it succeed (one hop as result). I couldn't try it from outside because the app I use doesn't allow to add custom options.

[ping and traceroute (inside)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GP8N.png)
[traceroute (outside)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HIwA.jpg)
[ping (outside)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOMGc.jpg)